# How to transform a string to graphical line in swift?

Tags: string, swift, macos, graphics

I have a string. This string has marked parts and I know the NSRanges for these different parts of string. I would like to transform this string to a graphical line comprised of different lines (different in thickness and color) corresponding to the different parts of string. All lines sizes should be proportional to the sizes of corresponding parts of string. What I have to use for implementation of such functionality in swift for OSX?

[image: From text to picture:]

Comment: Please be more specific.  This question should probably be decomposed into: how to I convert THIS string markup into a series of objects representing the components, how do I get the on-screen sizes of parts of laid-out text, and how do I draw lines on the screen using Cocoa.

Also: please add an image illustrating what you mean (hand drawn is OK)

Comment: @Alex Brown, I have added an image.

Comment: Nice.  Does the length allocated to a character change with the printed width of a character (m is longer than i)?

Comment: @Alex Brown, sorry, no.

Comment: I think you should take a step back from swift and ask "how would I solve this in mathematics/pseudocode".  Unless you are specifically concerned with how to turn numbers into on-screen pixels, which is a question you can research independently (look at CGPath, or OpenGL).

Comment: I mean ask yourself this question.  If you cannot solve that issue, then we have have something useful to discuss.

Comment: Just use a fixed width font and do it proportionally to the character count of each range